# Stripping chars in python

Tags: python

I know this is not very pretty code and that I'm sure there is an easier way but I'm more concerned on why python is not stripping the characters I requested it to.

```
import urllib, sgmllib


zip_code = raw_input('Give me a zip code> ')
url = 'http://www.uszip.com/zip/' + zip_code
print url

conn = urllib.urlopen('http://www.uszip.com/zip/' + zip_code)

i = 0
while i < 1000:
    for line in conn.fp:
            if i == 1:
                print line[7:-10]
                i += 1
            elif i == 344:
                line1 = line.strip()
                line2 = line1.strip('<td>') #its not stripping the characters 
                print line2[17:-60]
                i += 1
            else:
            i += 1
```

Comment: I've been reading documentation for the last hour with no success. Do you have helpful documentation you can point me to or are you simply being pretentious?

Comment: ["Return a copy of the string with **the leading and trailing characters** removed. The *chars* argument is a string specifying the **set** of characters to be removed.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you call it, it should remove any occurrence of the `<`, `>`, `t`, and `d` characters, and [*only at the beginning or end of the string*](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip):

```
>>> '<p>some test</p>'.strip('<td>')
'p>some test</p'
```

If you want to remove every occurrence of the substring `<td>`, use [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
>>> '<td>some test</td>'.replace('<td>', '')
'some test</td>'
```

Note that if you want to use that for some kind of input sanitization, it can be easily circumvented:

```
>>> '<td<td>>some test</td>'.replace('<td>', '')
'<td>some test</td>'
```

This is only one of many ways how people typically get screwed if they try to write their own HTML parsing code, so maybe you rather want to use a HTML parsing library like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or an XML parser like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

Answer (score 3):

```
            line2 = line1.strip('<td>') #its not stripping the characters
```

It doesn't strip the string `<td>`, rather it strips the characters in the string. So it'll strip away < and > and t and d, at the beginning and end of the string.

However, in general, that's a poor way to try and extract data from a web page. Look into BeautifulSoup for a better approac.

Comment: only at the beginning and end as well.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters:

Here is the detail of parameters:

```
chars: characters to be removed from beginning or end of the string.
```

Looks like it needs to be only at the beginning or ending of the string.  Otherwise, I would recommend using a regex.

Comment: Instead of trying to roll his own html/xml parser, he should really be using one of the available libraries like lxml as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: @gfortune, I totally agree, I was just trying to help him understand the behavior of the strip functions.  The recommendation was in that context, you're right I should have considered the greater problem at hand.